# Win10 Laptop Only turn off internal monitor but keep pc running AND usable

Tags: windows-10, display, microsoft-surface-pro

I'm working on a project and I want to embed an old laptop (Surface Pro with a cracked screen) under a keyboard. I'm looking for a way to have the internal monitor turned off (for battery and heat purpose) but the computer still running AND usable. By that I mean I'm not looking for a Power management solution where the screen goes off and comes back on as soon as the mouse moves or a key is pressed. I want to be able to use the computer remotely or as it (I'll keymap macros to do stuff on my others devices). Some laptops had this feature built-in.

I tried a few solutions but nothing was what I needed, the closest was using Usbmmidd to get a second virtual monitor and use "Only display on 2" to turn off the internal display but it had quirks: I don't want a second monitor and more importantly I want to be able to use the Displayport to mirror the monitor when needed, which Usbmmidd can't do because its a software display.

If anyone has an idea, even if I need to physically mod the hardware, I'm all hears ;)

Comment: Get a Surface Pro dock and then you should be able to turn the Surface monitor off.   https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/store/b/surface-accessories?ef_id=CjwKCAjw9MuCBhBUEiwAbDZ-7oepSE7EAVj7GX35w2q8hgCOOYtbG21nUSPQpA2bYIyrBkIDyBIHaBoChlMQAvD_BwE:G:s%2cCjwKCAjw9MuCBhBUEiwAbDZ-7oepSE7EAVj7GX35w2q8hgCOOYtbG21nUSPQpA2bYIyrBkIDyBIHaBoChlMQAvD_BwE:G:s&s_kwcid=AL!4249!3!284464548160!e!!g!!surface+pro+dock&OCID=AID2100847_SEM_CjwKCAjw9MuCBhBUEiwAbDZ-7oepSE7EAVj7GX35w2q8hgCOOYtbG21nUSPQpA2bYIyrBkIDyBIHaBoChlMQAvD_BwE:G:s

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52716615/virtual-fake-primary-monitor-in-windows-10

Comment: @John Thanks. This is already planned, to get a usb hub and display out to the back of the keyboard. But I don't see how this helps, even if I use the internal mini DP to fake a second monitor, can you explain the idea?

Comment: @Alex_Krug Thank you for your answer, I had no success with the driver :/

Comment: "But I don't see how this helps, ..."  A dock allow the laptop monitor to be turned off (what you want) and the external monitor used or remote access used. With a dock you can leave it closed and access remotely.

Comment: @John I get the part where the monitor will be turned off if external monitor or remote access is used. But if I want to use it without any of those? As I said, I'll program a software to interact with other devices (as a remote keyboard, OBS control, Ableton Live but without GUI, etc), so most of the times I need it to be running but without any external display or remote access. If the Surface Dock has special features I don't know about, please excuse me and thanks for your efforts to help

Comment: I use docking stations for our customers. I have not tried different parts or hubs